# Bessel Integral should be define precisely?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

Here is my integral:

```
Integrate[x^-1 E^(-p*x^2/2) BesselJ[n, a x] BesselJ[m, b x], {x, -∞, ∞}]
```

But I get

[image]

However for specific `n` and `m` ( for example `n == 0` and `m == 1`) I get the same result.

What is my mistake? Or, how can I find the result?

Comment: I guess you know that one of $m$ or $n$ has to be odd for the integral to be sensible. If you set, say $m$, with that constraint, you quickly find that if $n$ is odd, the integral is necessarily $0$. So the odd-even case is your nontrivial one, and some simplification can be done by cutting the interval in half (since the integrand is even) and multiplying by $2$ afterwards.

Comment: Thanks so much J.M for your good explanation, Actually the Mathematica doesn't show any result for 0 to infinity or -infinity to 0. it means I don't expect to get any result (according to any n , m and p values and even for unknown value of n.m.p ?)

Comment: What does `Assuming[p ∈ Reals && j ≥ 0 && k ≥ 0, Integrate[Exp[-p x^2] BesselJ[j, x] BesselJ[k, x]/x, {x, 0, ∞}]]` return for you?